# How do I declare an empty array as a function parameter correctly?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm currently doing some free exercises on codeStepByStep, and I particularly don't know how to solve the max_row one.

I need to input a 2D array as a function parameter, but it keeps showing me this error:

note: declaration of ‘arr’ as a multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first *

It seems like arrays should at least have a predefined column length, but it can't be dynamic like that right?
Here is my code :

```
int max=row(int numColumn, int arr[][numColumn], int numRow) {
    
    int i, j, sum = 0, maxSum = 0, a, b=0;
    
    for (i=0; i<numRow; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<numColumn; j++) {
            sum = arr[i][j] + sum;
        }
    if (maxSum < sum) {
        maxSum = sum;
        a = i;
    }
    if (maxSum = sum) {
        b = i;
    }
    if (b < a) {
        a = b;
    }
    }
    
    return a; 
}



int main()
{
    int list[4][3] = {
    {  3,   8,  12},
    {  2,   9,  17},
    { 43,  -8,  46},
    {203,  14,  97}
    };
    
    printf("%d", max_row(3, list, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

After asking here and there I found that I should start by declaring the column variable, so instead of this :

```
int max_row(int arr[][numColumn], int numRow, int numColumn)
```

it should be something like this as in the code above:

```
int max_row(int numColumn, int arr[][numColumn], int numRow)
```

but it won't be tested by the website.

The test question:

Write a function named max_row that accepts a number of rows and columns, and a 2-D array of integers, as parameters and that returns the index of the row where the elements add up to the greatest value. For example:

```
int list[4][3] = {
    {  3,   8,  12},
    {  2,   9,  17},
    { 43,  -8,  46},
    {203,  14,  97}
};
```

Then the call of max_row(list, 4, 3) should return 3. If there is a tie between two or more rows, return the row with the smaller index.

Your code should work for an array of any size at least 1x1.

Everything in main is me trying to see if the code works.

Comment: When you say "but it won't be tested by the website", what do you mean by that? What is the problems you have?

Comment: Also, do you know (or remember) the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what they do? If you build locally on your own system, with extra warnings enabled, what does the compiler say? Listen to the compiler and treat its warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: The website test it as  max_row(list, 4, 3), which means if switch the order it won' work.

Comment: And that was my bad I should have written == instead of =, in this one     if (maxSum = sum) {

Comment: Then the site can't pass an array of arrays, it must pass a pointer to a pointer. What is the text of your exercise *exactly*? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste it (as text), full and completely.

Comment: I edited my question and added the test question.

Comment: One of the major problems with so-called "competition", "judge" or other similar sites is that they often contain bad advice and bad code. Often also *invalid* code. This seems to be the case here. There's no way to pass an array of arrays without specifying the second dimension, and that can not be done with the arguments in the order specified. That exercise is flawed from the get-go, and an indicator that the site itself might not be that good.

Comment: Thanks, that got me hooked for the past two days.
I like to use such websites to really practice well but I guess time to find an alternative.

Answer (score -3):

It's because you can't declare a multi-dimensional array with a variable as dimension (c and c++ don't support it unless you declare them in the `heap` memory).
A solution could be this one:

```
#define MAX 10
int row(int numColumn, int arr[][MAX], int numRow)
{
int i, j, sum = 0, maxSum = 0, a, b = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            sum = arr[i][j] + sum;
        }
        if (maxSum < sum) {
            maxSum = sum;
            a = i;
        }
        if (maxSum == sum) {
            b = i;
        }
        if (b < a) {
            a = b;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

In the first line you declare a constant named MAX with value 10, then you use it to initialize the array.
Also I don't understand the use of maxSum and b, since you never actually use maxSum (you just initialized it) and you don't return b.
Plus you didn't even initialize a (you can't return a not initialized variable).

Moreover ***REMEMBER*** that you have to write `==` to make a comparison in an if statement, not `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I declared b because there is a part of the program that needs it. To return the row with the lesser index and the biggest sum. 
If predefine Max then that would leave me wit h a fixed number of columns so it won't work.

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) have been part of the C language since the C99 standard, published over 20 years ago. Even MSVC support most of it these days.

Comment: @Somep I know, but Visual Studio and some compilers don't allow that unless you specify the standard yourself

Comment: I see so that should solve this? I don't know  much since I haven't been learning C for more than a week

Comment: Compilers released the last ten or so years have had C99 as the default. The last five or so years C11 have been the default. There's also another problem: To be able to use your function the caller *must* use `MAX` as the second dimension. There's no way for it to work with "an array of any size".